# Stop content taking space under a sticky div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

In this example when I click the "link" on the sticky header, how can I make the linked content item (#mypara) to appear below the sticky div and not directly underneath it so its hidden?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height())
        {
            $('#sticky').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#sticky').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; background-color: #e3e3e3; }
#header { background-color: #cb5454; height: 140px; }
#sticky {
    background-color: #546bcb;
    height: 70px;
}
#sticky.fixed {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
p[id] {
  color:red;
  /*padding-top: 170px;*/
}
#footer { background-color: #cb5454; height: 140px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="sticky">sticky <a href="#mypara">link</a></div>
<div id="section">
<p>section 1</p>
<p>section 2</p>
<p>section 3</p>
<p>section 4</p>
<p>section 5</p>
<p>section 6</p>
<p>section 7</p>
<p>section 8 x</p>
<p>section 9</p>
<p id="mypara">section 0 xxxx</p>
<p>section 1</p>
<p>section 2</p>
<p>section 3</p>
<p>section 4</p>
<p>section 5</p>
<p>section 6</p>
<p>section 7</p>
<p>section 8</p>
<p>section 9</p>
<p>section 0</p>
<p>section 1</p>
<p>section 2</p>
<p>section 3 z</p>
<p>section 4</p>
<p>section 5</p>
<p>section 6</p>
<p>section 7</p>
<p>section 7</p>
<p>section 8</p>
<p>section 8</p>
<p>section 9</p>
<p>section 0</p>
<p>section 1</p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section </p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
<p>section</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">foot</div>
```

This fiddle was inherited from other SO threads so I think this is the right way to do a sticky div that only becomes sticky after scrolling (I couldn't get position:sticky to do anything, but position:fixed seems to be whats recommended in a number of threads).

[image]

The above pic shows where I want it to land when the link is clicked

Comment: First : use `position: sticky` for your sticky div. This way you avoid this JQuery function. Then you can use JQuery to scroll down to the section on click of the link.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle to try this and sticky does not work at all

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: OK so making it sticky got rid of the javascript but the same problem with the linked target ending up underneath the sticky div still exists: http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/8m3qwont/5/

Comment: I'm trying to find a way too. will post a solution when I do.

Comment: Here's one possible solution, a ::before pseudo element ? http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/8m3qwont/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jean-Marc Zimmer pointed out, using Sticky removed the need for javascript, but still had the problem of the element coming up underneath the sticky div.

One solution was to add a pseudo element:

```
p[id]::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 60px; /* fixed header height*/
  margin: -60px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

Full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/8m3qwont/14/

Note that position:sticky does not work in IE11.

Note that adding padding or a border to p[id] (not in ::before) stops this effect working. No idea why!

Answer (score 0):

In scroll function, you can first try to get `window.pageYOffset` which will give you current position of the scroll and then you can try using `scrollTo(x, y)` method of the window. `Y` value in the `scrollTo` will be the `window.pageYOffset` minus the height of your div. (`window.pageYOffset` - `height of your div`)

Answer (score 0):

`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height())
            {
                $('#sticky').addClass('fixed');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#sticky').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
//add this. it will scroll to the div #mypara with 150px top offset
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href$=\\#])').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 150
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; background-color: #e3e3e3; }
    #header { background-color: #cb5454; height: 140px; }
    #sticky {
        background-color: #546bcb;
        height: 70px;
    }
    #sticky.fixed {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    p[id] {
      color:red;
      /*padding-top: 170px;*/
    }
    #footer { background-color: #cb5454; height: 140px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="sticky">sticky <a href="#mypara">link</a></div>
    <div id="section">
    <p>section 1</p>
    <p>section 2</p>
    <p>section 3</p>
    <p>section 4</p>
    <p>section 5</p>
    <p>section 6</p>
    <p>section 7</p>
    <p>section 8 x</p>
    <p>section 9</p>
    <p id="mypara">section 0 xxxx</p>
    <p>section 1</p>
    <p>section 2</p>
    <p>section 3</p>
    <p>section 4</p>
    <p>section 5</p>
    <p>section 6</p>
    <p>section 7</p>
    <p>section 8</p>
    <p>section 9</p>
    <p>section 0</p>
    <p>section 1</p>
    <p>section 2</p>
    <p>section 3 z</p>
    <p>section 4</p>
    <p>section 5</p>
    <p>section 6</p>
    <p>section 7</p>
    <p>section 7</p>
    <p>section 8</p>
    <p>section 8</p>
    <p>section 9</p>
    <p>section 0</p>
    <p>section 1</p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section </p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    <p>section</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">foot</div>
```

`